# If cell in specific row contains "x", how to do I retrieve the specific column name where x is present using Java

Tags: java, excel, selenium, for-loop

Sample excel sheet (I am using a much larger excel sheet):

| Column0 | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row0 | red | x | x |  | x |
| row1 | orange | x |  | x |  |
| row2 | yellow |  | x | x | x |
| row3 | green | x | x |  | x |
| row4 | blue | x |  | x |  |
| row5 | purple | x |  | x |  |
| row6 | pink |  |  | x |  |

Let's propose I want to select row3. How do I retrieve the name of the columns where the x' are present? For row3, I want to display on my console "column2 column3 column5". I am also trying to start at a specific column index hence I had a column that strayed from having x's. So for the example, I need to iterate from column2-->column5, then identify in row3 which of the cells have x's and then identify the name of those columns. My code below I had real time numbers I am using.

```
//find x's in certain row
        //pick row 15
        int rowIndex = 15;
        //start at column 9 and iterate to column 33
        for (int columnIndex = 9; columnIndex<33; columnIndex++){
            Row row = CellUtil.getRow(rowIndex, sheet);
            Cell cell = CellUtil.getCell(row, columnIndex);
            //if row contains x in specific cells, get column name
            //progTypes is the name of the columns appearing in row index 0
            if(cell.getStringCellValue() == "x") {
                for(int progTypes = 9; progTypes < 33; progTypes++) {
                    for (int firstRow = 0; firstRow < 0; firstRow++) {
                        Row fRow = CellUtil.getRow(firstRow, sheet);
                        Cell fColumn = CellUtil.getCell(fRow, progTypes);
                        String columnName = fColumn.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println(columnName);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you don't need the two for loops inside your if case since you already got the cell index.

```
if(cell.getStringCellValue() == "x") {
  Row fRow = CellUtil.getRow(0, sheet);
  Cell fColumn = CellUtil.getCell(fRow, columnIndex);
  String columnName = fColumn.getStringCellValue();
  System.out.println(columnName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). There are a number of examples how to access and modify spreadsheets at https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/examples.html